# Is a number written in roman numerals a roman numeral, or is each of its digits a roman numeral?

Tags: word-choice

Say I've got "VIII". How do I refer to that? Is it "a roman numeral", is it "roman numerals", because a single roman numeral is one digit, or is it something else, like "roman number"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/129111?redirectedFrom=numeral#eid) entry indicates that any single digit or any number is called a 'numeral'.

For example, one of the entries :

> 1935   J. O'Hara Appointment in Samarra (U.K. ed.) vii. 197   The little clock had no numerals but only squares of metal where the numerals were supposed to be,

expresses the numbers one to twelve as 'numerals'. If the numbers were in Roman style, then there would be two digits for some of the 'numerals'.

Where individual digits are in view the term 'numeral characters' is used :

> 1728   E. Chambers Cycl. at Character.   **Numeral Characters**, are those used to express Numbers.

> 1840   Penny Cycl. XVI. 366/2   Distinct **numeral characters** are found to have existed..among the Chinese, Indians, and Arabs.

Answer (score 1):

Each digit (I, V, X etc.) is a 'roman numeral'. The entire number would be described as 'expressed in roman numerals'.

I notice, however, that Unicode characters (Ⅷ, ⅺ, Ⅿ etc.) representing entire numbers are described as a 'numeral'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I would tend to agree that VIII is a Roman numeral since it represents a discrete integer. However I'm less sure that Roman representation of larger integers involving repeated characters are numerals. For instance MCMIX (1909) obviously consists of three numerals (M, CM, IX) but what about MMXXI?